# how can i disable user touch of a UIbarbutton without disabling?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uibarbuttonitem

i have a UiBarButton item in my Toolbar.i need to deactivate the user touch interaction in 
UiBarButton. there is no **setUserInteractionEnabled** property to it.  when i am hiding it there is no proper visibility .can any one tell me that how can i disable user touch interaction of a UIbarbutton without disabling it?

Comment: Hello Christina, You can check your answer as I posted below. USe the UIBarButtonItem.

Answer (score 5):

To have a title in a UIToolBar, add a UIBarButtonItem to your toolbar and then set its customView property to a UILabel.  You can then set the text of the label and not have any highlighting, etc.

```
// In @interface section:
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *titleButtonItem;

// In @implementation section:
- (void)viewDidLoad {
  ...
  UILabel *titleLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
  self.titleButtonItem.customView = titleLabel;
  titleLabel.text = @"Some Title Text";
  [titleLabel sizeToFit];
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this:

```
[barButtonItem setTarget:nil];
[barButtonItem setAction:nil];
```

The button looks enabled but it will not receive any touch event.

Comment: Thanks , saved me some time. I think that setting only the action to nil will also disable it.

Answer (score 2):

You can always do:

```
[yourbutton removeTarget:nil 
                  action:NULL 
        forControlEvents:UIControlEventAllEvents];
```

That will remove all actions and targets associated with the button.

Comment: there is no  removeTarget:nil 
                  action:NULL 
        forControlEvents:UIControlEventAllEvents]; methods for uibarbutton

Answer (score 2):

**Obj - c**

```
UIButton *barButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[barButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[barButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"] forState:UIControlStateDisabled];
barButton.frame = CGRectMake(10.0,10.0,50,50);
UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:aButton];
backButton.enabled = NO;
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButton;
```

**Swift 4**

**For Button Image**

```
let barButton = UIButton(type: .custom)
    barButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "image.png"), for: .normal)
    barButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "image.png"), for: .disabled)
    barButton.frame = CGRect(x: 10.0, y: 10.0, width: 50, height: 50)
    let backButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: aButton)
    backButton.isEnabled = false
    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButton
```

**For Button Title**

```
let btnTitle = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Your Button title", style: .plain, target: nil, action:nil)
    btnTitle.setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont(name: "fontname", size: 14.0)!], for: .normal)
    btnTitle.setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont(name: "fontname", size: 14.0)!], for: .disabled)
    btnTitle.isEnabled = false
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems = [btnTitle]
```

Answer (score 1):

Make a custom property associated with your button.

Let's say your button fires the action below:

```
-(IBAction)fireOnButtonPress:(id)sender {
    // do something
}
```

Make an instance variable such as `BOOL interactionEnabled;` and in your viewDidLoad or other init method set it to `YES`

```
interactionEnabled = YES;
```

When you need to disable button interaction, simply set it to `NO`

```
interactionEnabled = NO;
```

In your method that is fired when the button is pressed, just add an if-condition checking to see what the state of `interactionEnabled` is, like so:

```
-(IBAction)fireOnButtonPress:(id)sender {
    if(interactionEnabled) {
        // do something
    }
    // otherwise ignore button press
}
```

This won't disable the button, but it will prevent the user from interacting with it when you don't want them to.

Answer (score 0):

You alloc-init a custom UILabel as a UIBarbuttonItem (how? see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9529106/adding-a-custom-label-in-toolbar-doesnt-work/9530342#comment12109235_9530342)) with no text and it should be large enough to cover the UIBarbuttonItem you want to disable. It worked for me.

Answer (score -3):

You can find your answer here.

In .h File:

```
IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *button1;
```

In .m File:

```
[button1 setEnabled:FALSE];
```

Create the UIBarButtonItem as IBOutlet in .h file and access in the implementation file and you can use the problerty of UIBarButtonItem - "setEnabled" to make it enable or disable.

Let me know if you need more help.

Comment: he specifically said "without disabling it"

Comment: UIBarButtonItem doesn't have a userInteractionEnabled property.