# How to disable userinteraction with UIBarButtonItem?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uibarbuttonitem

When the user presses the bar button, it changes its color to grey. But the color of the bar button shouldn't change when the state is `pressed`. I have the same problem like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6212827/how-can-i-disable-user-touch-of-a-uibarbutton-without-disabling) which never got solved and every answer is not working. There is no `setUserInteractionEnabled` property. But disabling the whole bar button brings an alpha effect on the bar button wich I dont want to.

Any advice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're right, there's no elegant solution. The best way to do this is to use a UIButton in the toolbar. Look at the EDIT part in this answer: [How do I remove UIBarButtonItem glow programtically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13622941/how-do-i-remove-uibarbuttonitem-glow-programtically)

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem , i solved it by setting same image for both  UIControlStateNormal and UIControlStateDisabled.Then disable the bar button.

```
UIImage *buttonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ic_launcher.png"];
UIButton *aButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[aButton setImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[aButton setImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateDisabled];
aButton.frame = CGRectMake(0.0,0.0,50,50);
UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:aButton];
backButton.enabled = NO;
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButton;
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I think that only setting the disabled state is enough, since you hardcode the bar button in a disabled state